# Where can I see the file format of my SD card on Android?

Tags: external-sd, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9, system-info

Where can I see the  file format of my SD card on Android?

I use a Samsung Galaxy s9 with Android 9.

---

**Note a dupe because here we're talking about SD cards.**